# C++ Spell checking program with two classes; Dictionary and word

Tags: c++

Here is the specification for the code:
You are to use the Word and Dictionary classes defined below and write all member functions and any necessary supporting functions to achieve the specified result.

The Word class should dynamically allocate memory for each word to be stored in the dictionary.

The Dictionary class should contain an array of pointers to Word. Memory for this array must be dynamically allocated. You will have to read the words in from the file. Since you do not know the "word" file size, you do not know how large to allocate the array of pointers. You are to let this grow dynamically as you read the file in. Start with an array size of 8, When that array is filled, double the array size, copy the original 8 words to the new array and continue.

You can assume the "word" file is sorted, so your Dictionary::find() function must contain a binary search algorithm. You might want to save this requirement for later - until you get the rest of your program running.

Make sure you store words in the dictionary as lower case and that you convert the input text to the same case - that way your Dictionary::find() function will successfully find "Four" even though it is stored as "four" in your Dictionary.

Here is my code so far.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


class Word
{
    char* word_;
public:
    Word(const char* text = 0);
    ~Word() { delete[] word_; word_ = nullptr; }
    const char* word() const;
};



Word::Word(const char* arg)
    : word_(new char[strlen(arg) + 1])
{
    strcpy(word_, arg);
}


const char* Word::word() const
{

    return word_;
}


class Dictionary
{
    Word** words_;
    unsigned int capacity_;   // max number of words Dictionary can hold 
    unsigned int numberOfWordsInDictionary_;
    void resize() {
        capacity_ = capacity_ * 2;
        cout << "Size = " << capacity_ << endl;
    };
    void addWordToDictionary(char* word) { words_ += *word; };
public:
    Dictionary(const char* filename);
    ~Dictionary() {
        delete[] words_; words_ = nullptr;
    };
    bool find(const char* word);


};

Dictionary::Dictionary(const char * filename)
    : words_(new Word*[8]), capacity_(8), numberOfWordsInDictionary_(0)
{
    ifstream fin(filename);

    if (!filename) {
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    }

    char buffer[32];
    while (fin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
    {
        if (numberOfWordsInDictionary_ == capacity_)
        {
            resize();
        }

        addWordToDictionary(buffer);

    }
}

bool Dictionary::find(const char * left)
{
    int last = capacity_ - 1,
        first = 0,
        middle;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last) {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (strcmp(left, reinterpret_cast<char*>(words_[middle])) == 0) {
            found = true;
        }
        else if (left > reinterpret_cast<char*>(words_[middle]))
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
    }

    return found;
}
;

bool cleanupWord(char x[] ) {
    bool lower = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (x[i]) {
        char c = x[i];
        putchar(tolower(c));
        lower = true;
    }
    return lower;
}



    int main()
    {

        char buffer[32];
        Dictionary Websters("words.txt");
        ifstream fin("gettysburg.txt");
        cout << "\nSpell checking " << "gettysburg.text" << "\n\n";
        while (fin >> buffer) {
            if (cleanupWord(buffer) == true) {
                if (!Websters.find(buffer)) {
                    cout << buffer << " not found in the Dictionary\n";
                }
            }
        }

        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

When I run the program it stops after outputting "spellchecking Gettysburg.txt" and I don't know why. Thank you!

Comment: How certain are you that "gettysburg.txt" was successfully opened? Search term: Working Directory. Also watch out for [the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Both of your classes break it and this leads to a future disaster.

Comment: On second read, The Rule of Three's not so important here. Learn it anyway because you can't write good quality, non-trivial C++ without it.

Comment: Clearly it's not going into your while  loop, mostly likely because the file failed to open. Always check that files open, there's just too many reasons why they might not.

Comment: BTW on a related point, this code is wrong, `if (!filename) {
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    }` it should be `if (!fin) {
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    }` or slightly more clearly `if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open file!" << endl;
    }` Who knows you might find that your dictionary file failed to open as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this problem is the text files have not been opened. Add a check with `is_open` to make sure they have been opened.

When using Relative Paths (any path that does not go all the way back to the root of the file system (and is an Absolute Path)), take care that the program is being run from the directory you believe it to be. It is not always the same directory as the executable. Search Term to use to learn more about this: Working Directory.

Now on to other reasons this program will not work:

```
void addWordToDictionary(char* word) { words_ += *word; };
```

is not adding words to the dictionary. Instead it is advancing the address at which `words_` points by the numeric value of the letter at `*word`. This is extremely destructive as it loses the pointer to the buffer allocated for `words_` in the constructor making `delete[] words_;` in the `Dictionary` destructor ineffective and probably fatal.

Instead you want to (Note I use *want to* with a bit of trepidation. What you really want to do is use `std::vector` and `std::string`, but I strongly suspect this would upset the assignment's marker)

1. Dynamically allocate a new `Word` with `new`.
2. Place this word in a free spot in the `words_` array. Something along the lines of `words_[numberOfWordsInDictionary_] = myNewWord;`
3. Increase `numberOfWordsInDictionary_` by 1.

Note that the `Word`s allocated with `new` must all be released in the `Dictionary` destructor. You will want a `for` loop to help with this.

In addition, I would move the

```
    if (numberOfWordsInDictionary_ == capacity_)
    {
        resize();
    }
```

from `Dictionary` to `addWordToDictionary` so that any time `addWordToDictionary` is called it is properly sized.

Hmmm.  While we're at it, let's look at `resize`

```
void resize() {
    capacity_ = capacity_ * 2;
    cout << "Size = " << capacity_ << endl;
};
```

This increases the object's `capacity_` but does nothing to allocate more storage for `words_`. This needs to be corrected. You must:

1. Double the value of `capacity_`. You already have this.
2. Allocate a larger buffer to hold the replacement of `words_` with `new`.
3. Copy all of the `Word`s in `words_` to the larger buffer.
4. Free the buffer currently pointed to by `words_`
5. Point `words_` at the new, larger buffer.

## Addendum

I haven't looked closely at `find` because the carnage required to fix the reading and storage of the dictionary will most likely render `find` unusable even if it does currently work. The use of `reinterpret_cast<char*>` is an alarm bell, though. There should be no reason for a cast, let alone the most permissive of them all, in a find function. Rule of thumb: When you see a `reinterpret_cast` and you don't know what it's for, assume it's hiding a bug and approach it with caution and suspicion.

In addition to investigating the Rule of Three  mentioned in the comments, look into the [Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This will allow you to make a much simpler, and probably more efficient,  dictionary based around `Word* words_`, where `words_` will point to an array of `Word` directly instead of pointers to `Word`s.